# mathematical analysis separable metric space problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Supose $X$ is a metric space and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$ continuous and Surjective function (onto)
show that $X$ is separable.

Comment: I mean.. this is a very basic exercise. Did you actually give any effort?

Comment: i am anundergraduate student i dont know how to solve it, could you help ?

Comment: i dont know how this comment add something usefull to the post and got an upvote

Comment: What is your definition of Separable?

Comment: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space if it exist a $Y\subseteq X $ where $Y$ is countable and  $\bar{Y}=X $ then $X$ is separable

Comment: @PetrosK This comment got an upvote as it is consent in this community that people should show what they have tried :) People are usually quick to vote to close questions otherwise. This is nothing personal, many people just feel that the aim of this site is to discuss interesting math and not to solve homework problems for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$1)$ $\mathbb R$ is separable: [$\overline{\mathbb Q} = \mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/completion-of-rational-numbers-via-cauchy-sequences/).

$2)$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two metric spaces and $A$ be any subset of $X$. If $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, [then $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236907/closure-of-continuous-image-of-closure).

$3)$ Let $M$ and $N$ be any two sets. If $f: M \to N$ is any mapping and $A \subset M$ is countable, [then $f(A)$ is countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Image_of_Countable_Set_under_Mapping_is_Countable).